# Trying to chainload Windows Vista/Windows 7 and Ubuntu with grub

Tags: windows, linux, grub, multi-boot

I was running out of space on my internal drive, so I bought a new drive and I am trying to take all the files from my old internal drive and put them on my new drive. Including the OS that was installed on my old drive. I made a exact copy of my old drive and put it on an external hard drive. I installed Ubuntu on my new drive. So now I am wondering if I get all the files and the OS from my old drive onto my new drive in a new partition if I can chainload Ubuntu, Win Vista, and Win 7 with grub.

So my questions are exactly:
1. Am I able to just copy the OS files over to the new drive and have it work without a fresh install of the OS. The OS are Win Vista and Win 7

2. How exactly do I chainload Ubuntu, Win Vista, and Win 7 with grub. I mean specifically. I believe I need to edit the grub.cfg file right? I just need to know one OS. Win Vista is on HD0 and partition /dev/sda3

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you also need to have the proper boot records on your partitions. But honestly, I would recommend reinstalling the OSes, because such tweaking may cause strange compatibility issues.